# Sqlalchemy, merge two queries

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to merge these two queries together, to get all messages sent and received between two users. anyone know how, please, thank you.

```
messages = db.session.query(Message).filter(Message.sender_id == user.id, Message.recipient_id == current_user.id)

messagestwo = db.session.query(Message).filter(Message.sender_id == current_user.id, Message.recipient_id == user.id)
```

Comment: You might want a union: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union

Comment: OMG thank you, exactly what i wanted!

Comment: Of course another option would be to use `or_(and_(...), and_(...))` predicate in `filter()` in a single query.